# Replacing certain elements in a list

Tags: list, haskell

I am trying to write code that will take a list and give me a list where an element after an element bigger or equal to 10 is replaced with a number I choose. In this case it is a number already in list +1 ([10,(0+1),0,0...]. 
That means, that after running function on sample two, the output will be [10,1,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

However, I need to write a function `zstoints1` that will run the `replace1` function through the whole list and got a bit tangled up in syntax and instead of returning [10,1,0,0,10,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] it returns [10,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0].

```
sample :: [Int]
sample= [-20,0,0,10,0,10,-20,-20,0,10,0,0,0,-20]

sample2 :: [Int]
sample2= [10,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

replace::[Int]->Int->Int->[Int]
replace [] _ _ = []
replace (x:xs) i n   | i == 0 = n:xs
                    | otherwise = x:replace xs (i-1) n 

replace1 :: [Int]->[Int]
replace1 (x:xs) = replace (x:xs) 1 ((x:xs)!!1 + 1)

zstoints1 :: [Int]->[Int]
zstoints1 [] = []
zstoints1 (x:xs)    |x<=10 = x: zstoints1 xs
                    |x>=10 = x: zstoints1 (tail(replace1 (x:xs)))
```

Where did I make a mistake and what could be a correct way to write it?

PS: I wrote replace functions in a complicated way because I plan to use them further in my code.

Comment: This is not the issue, but let me comment on your `replace1`. It crashes on `[]`, to start. It also crashes on `[x]`, since it tries to access the second element with `(x:xs)!!1`. It calls `replace` to replace the second element. Perhaps you could handle the cases `[]` and `[x]` separately, and then let `replace1 (x0:x1:xs) = x0:x1+1:xs`. That looks much simpler to me, if you want to increment the second element.

Comment: "a number already in the list + 1". *Which* number? What should the result for `sample` be?

Comment: I know, however after I get this working, I will also want to use it to increment 7th,8th and 9th element. This will be a bit complicated that way.

Comment: @chepner the number in the next position

Comment: So `[10 0 5]` should produce `[10 6 5]`? Or are you just incrementing the next value to get `[10 1 5]`?

Comment: @chepner to get ```[10 1 5]```

Comment: Question is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the issue:

```
zstoints1 (x:xs)    |x<=10 = x: zstoints1 xs
                   --^^^^^--
```

This should only trigger when `x < 10`, since you want to call `replace1` on `10`, instead.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a perfect opportunity to use [`scanl1`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:scanl1) which lives in the Data.List package and available in Prelude by default.

```
doit :: [Int] -> [Int]
doit = scanl1 (\p c -> if p >= 10 then 1 else c)

*Main> doit [-20,0,0,10,0,10,-20,-20,0,10,0,0,0,-20]
[-20,0,0,10,1,10,1,-20,0,10,1,0,0,-20]
*Main> doit [10,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[10,1,0,0,10,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```